# AWK скрипты, поиск значения

Tags: linux, awk

Не могу найти "/ls.txt", дает ошибку на слэш.

```
du -a | awk '{if(//ls.txt$){print $2}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//ls.txt$
```

это некорректная запись регулярного выражения. корректно будет:

```
/ls.txt$/
```

а если надо включить в выражение и слэш, то его надо «заэскейпить»:

```
/\/ls.txt$/
```

---

p.s. к слову, и условный оператор у вас лишний. программа *awk* может сразу отбирать строки, подпадающие под регулярное выражение:

```
awk '/выражение/{действия}'
```

в вашем примере:

```
$ du -a | awk '/\/ls.txt$/{print $2}'
```